# Change image background using next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to create a Character Selection for Airconsole. 
I thought I could create this using a Jquery method like a Gallery.
So I need a *previous* button, a *next* button and the character display.
It seems that I am making a mistake that I can't figure out, because I am not used to working with Javascript.

```js
var speed = 100;

$(".prev").click(function() {
  var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.char_display").children(":visible"),
    last = $(this).parent().next("ul.char_display").children(":last"),
    prev = now.prev();
  prev = prev.index() == -1 ? last : prev;
  now.fadeOut(speed, function() {
    prev.fadeIn(speed);
  });
});

$(".next").click(function() {
  var now = $(this).parent().next("ul.char_display").children(':visible'),
    first = $(this).parent().next("ul.char_display").children(':first'),
    next = now.next();
  next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
  now.fadeOut(speed, function() {
    next.fadeIn(speed);
  });
});

$(".char_display li").click(function() {
  var first = $(this).parent().children(':first'),
    next = $(this).next();
  next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
  $(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {
    next.fadeIn(speed);
  });
});
```

```css
.prev {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.next {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.char_display li {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.char_display li:first-child {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.char_display {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.char {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#char1 {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#char2 {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="characterScreen_characterBlock">
  <div id="characterScreen_leftArrow" class="characterScreen_left" ontouchend="otherChar(true);" ontouchend="otherChar(true);">
    <div class="prev"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="characterScreen_characterDisplay" class="characterScreen_center">
    <ul class="char_display">
      <li>
        <div class="char" id="char1"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="char" id="char2"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="characterScreen_rightArrow" class="characterScreen_right" ontouchend="otherChar(false);" ontouchend="otherChar(false);">
    <div class="next"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What problem did you encounter, exactly?

Comment: Well I get a blue Background for the character_display. Which is right. But using the next or prev button does not change anything

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the Console

Answer (score 0):

I haven't look through all of your code, but I am pretty sure

```
$(this).parent().next("ul.char_display").children("...")
```

doesn't do what you want it to. Especially since it always returns an error for pushing the next-button.

`$.next()` returns the next DOM-element. `characterScreen_rightArrow` however doesn't have a next element (in this snippet)

What you were searching for is probably `$.siblings()`. Personally I would however use the qualifier `#characterScreen_characterDisplay ul` instead of searching for it relatively.